# Proving a function to be differentiable using continuity

Tags: derivatives

The fact that a differentiable function must be continuous is well known, and the fact that a continuous function need not be differentiable is also well known. However, if I say that $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are both continuous at $x = a$ then is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x = a$. I can't find a rigorous proof of this, nor a counter example
. Providing either would be helpful

Comment: **Proof:** Since $f'$ is continuous at $a$, then, in particular, $f'(a)$ exists, which means that $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

Comment: You mean perhaps that if $f'(x)$ has a limit when $x\to a$ and $x\neq a$ then $f$ is differentiable at $a$. This is true, if $f'$ exists in a punctured open interval centered at $a$ and $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $f’(x)$ is continuous at $x = a$ already implies that $f’(a)$ exists, by definition of continuity. So $f$ is differentiable at $x = a$.

Answer (score 0):

Continuously differentiable means that the derivative exists at any point and that the function $f'$ is continuous.